# are you unable to use plugins in build.phonegap.com since version 3.0?

Tags: plugins, cordova, build, command-line-interface

I was using build.phonegap.com in it's simplest way.  That is: no sdk and no phonegap framework installed on my computer; no git or svn repository used.  I just upload a zip with my html, css and js files.

But now I need to use the File plugin.

I found several posts (here and elsewhere) taking about using the CLI to add plugins and to build remotely since phonegap 3.0 (which doesn't use the config.xml to add plugins anymore, but instead it uses the CLI).

If you just used to upload a zip file to build.phonegap.com, are you now unable to use plugins since phonegap 3.0??

If that virtue is gone, what is now the simplest way for doing it? I currently use Aptana 3.0.  Do I have to install Eclipse and install the phonegap framework?  Do I have to create git of svn repository?  Is that now the simplest way for using plugins in the cloud-based build service?

Is there a way to use the build.phonegap.com service with phonegap 2.x??  I have not found it yet.

This is taking me out of schedule for the imminent delivery of an ongoing project.

Please advise.

Comment: what does your config.xml file look like?

Comment: I tried, together and separately, tags <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/> and <!--gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" version="0.2.3" /-->.  But that was before realizing that in phonegap 3.x the config.xml file is not used any more to add plugins.  When running the app, I recieve error "can't find variable: LocalFileSystem" and that's when I started googling and found that now I have to use CLI.

Comment: if you are on build.phonegap.com you have to use a config.xml to load plugins. File plugin info: https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/219

Comment: I just signed up to pastebin.com.  The config.xml file is here http://pastebin.com/nehBfffB. I also realized the xml contains a tag indicating phonegap-version to be used is 2.9.0.  From the link you put is from the one I took the tags. So I'm doing something else wrong.  Are you currently adding plugins via the xml (without CLI) and everything works ok?

Comment: the lowest version of the File plugin that I see is 0.2.1 and it says is for phonegap 3.x.  Aren't the plugins backward compatible if I am supposedly building with phonegap 2.9??

Comment: In PhoneGap versions lower than 3.X there aren't plugins for core features, they are just features and are automatically available.

Comment: the build.phonegap.com site says "your app will always be built with the most up-to-date SDK for the platform you are targeting". Does this apply to the phonegap framewrok as well or am I effectively building with phonegap 2.9.0 by using tag <preference name="phonegap-version" value="2.9.0" />??  For version 2.9, do I still need tag <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>?? BTW the link http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file gives a "server not found" error.

Comment: If you use <preference name="phonegap-version" value="2.9.0" /> then your project will be built in 2.9.0 and you will only need to add the feature tag if you are building for Android. Otherwise you can just use the methods described here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File

Comment: @DawsonLoudon thank you.  Your replies helped me realize several things and now I know where the problem is not.  And maybe I have found where the problem is.  Now I'll find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In phonegap 2.x plugins like File were part of the core, so there was no need to include them through the config.xml file.

In phonegap 3.x every plugin has to be included through the config.xml file.  BUT for plugins to work, the root index.html header must have a

```
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
```

phonegap.js is provided (kind of injected) by the build.phonegap.com service, so I don't have to have it on my source code.

The script tag was the only thing I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Put the config.xml in the www directory. And then upload only www.zip on build.phone.com.